# Nokogiri and IMDb

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I'm getting started with Nokogiri and trying to extract some data from IMDB. However, IMDB's html is a bit funny and can't seem to find the css selectors a few things such as the creator's name for example: http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1439629/. How could I get what I'm after ?

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

url = "http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1439629/"
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))  
puts doc.at_css("h1").text.strip
```

Comment: what I have is this  

"<a class="" onclick="(new Image()).src='/rg/title-overview/creator-1/images/b.gif?link=%2Fname%2Fnm1363595%2F';" href="/name/nm1363595/">Dan Harmon</a>"

Comment: And I don't really understand how I'm supposed to get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a beginner tutorial for Nokogiri which explains how to VERY EASILY find what you're looking for helped by firebug and its copy CSS function.

http://ruby.bastardsbook.com/chapters/html-parsing/

Answer (score 0):

This one works:

```
puts doc.at_css("div.txt-block a").text.strip
> Dan Harmon
```

Comment: but wait, why does this return only Dan Harmon when  Joel McHale, Danny Pudi and Donald Glover have the same attribute ?

Comment: It's getting the first one with the same attribute. `@doc.css( "div.txt-block a" )[1].text` => `"Joel McHale"` `@doc.css( "div.txt-block a" )[2].text` => `"Danny Pudi"`